# Populate across database with @nestjs/mongosoe

Tags: nestjs

In mongoose I can populate cross database with `ref` option when define Schema like

```js
const connection = await mongoose.connect(mongoDbUri)
const db1 = connection.useDb('db1')
const db2 = connection.useDb('db2')

const GeneralInfoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  address: String,
  phoneNumber : Number
})

const GeneralInfoModel = db1.model('general_infos',GeneralInfoSchema  )

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name : String,
  generalInfo: {type : mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref :GeneralInfoModel  }
})

const UserModel = db2.model('users',UserSchema )

UserModel.find().populate('generalInfo')
```

How can I do like this with `@nestjs/mongoose` since there are no way to reach `model` or `connection` in `@Prop()` decorator?